# No excuse for [odd-behavior]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[odd-behavior](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/odd-behavior) doesn't seem to be very meaningful. It's very vague as it just means something is acting oddly, failing to denote any cohesive topic. I suggest that this tag be deleted.

Comment: Eventually anything which is not working is behaving oddly from the user's point of view, even if it's not meant to work that way. Too general & undescriptive.

Comment: I suggest it was Moshe, in the Conservatory, with the red smart phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Done

Tag removed from all questions. Where appropriate, more descriptive tags have been added in its place.

Answer (score 1):

Odd behavior from the machine can cause [ODD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppositional_defiant_disorder) behavior from the user...

...

...

...

Okay, I'll see myself out.